# Visual Studio Code en Linux Mint

Tags: c, linux, vscode, linux-mint

no puedo compilar C en Visual Studio Code por que cada vez que lo intento me sale por pantalla:

> Se han detectado errores de #include. Actualice el valor de includePath. El subrayado ondulado está deshabilitado para esta unidad de traducción (/home/juan/Documentos/C/Prueba.c).C/C++(1696)
>   no se puede abrir el archivo origen (código de error "stdio.h")

Alguien sabe como solucionarlo??

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que seguramente no seteaste el compilerPath, requerido cuando querés compilar desde VStudio Code.
Debés setear el valor en la configuración del IDE. Te copio el ejemplo que utilicé en algún momento:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "MinGW",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Users/Steven Upton/scoop/apps/gcc/current/bin/g++.exe",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 3
}
```